# Objective C binding on MonoTouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

Hi i'm currently developing a monotouch app, where i need to use the IDBlue framework for connecting from the ipad to their blueetooth reader, but is shipped as a framework without a .a, how i should proceed to make the binding so i can use it on monotouch?

Comment: I do not know that framework, but when getting started with bindings, I'd recommend you start by mapping one method at a time, don't do all at once, otherwise you'll have a lot of variables to handle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a Bindings project in your solution.

[This document](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) describes the whole process.

Also there is a tool ([Parser.exe](http://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/f84cbb892691998c7424e8fedc08854d1e976816/src/parse.cs)) to help generate bindings.  Surprisingly this tool is not mentioned in the "Binding Objective-C Types" document.  It is not a complete solution but will give you a good start.

Comment: So you think that i can do that also without having the .a lib file?, and i should link the framework with the gcc arguments?

Comment: You can use either a framework (the binary file you need to link to is inside the framework directory, just treat it like an .a file) or a .a file.

Comment: If somebody is looking for the tool to generate bindings, I have put it into a [separate github repo for convenience](https://github.com/stampsy/monotouch-binding-generator). Saves you five minutes. (Yes, it's *exactly* the same as MonoMac's parse.cs).